# Program type already present: jpos.JposException

Tags: android, javapos, bixolon-printer

I got the exception

> 'Program type already present: jpos.JposException '

when trying to rebuild the app, the problem appeared after I added the `bixolon_printer_v127.jar`,`icu4j-58_1.jar`,`jpos117-controls.jar` and `xerces.jar`, and it was running perfectly before that,

can anyone help ?

build.gradle(Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.andalus.mobilesales"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2') with module('commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2')
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    implementation files('libs/Sewoo_Android_1076B.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.12'
    implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/bixolon_printer_v127.jar')
    implementation files('libs/icu4j-58_1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jpos117-controls.jar')
    implementation files('libs/xerces.jar')
}
```

build.gradle (project:app)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's giving error because `JposException` class is present in tow or more than that.
In your Gradle file exclude your `jpos.JposException` class from implementation in your module level gradle file as follows:

```
implementation (files('libs/jpos117-controls.jar')){
    exclude group: 'jpos.JposException'
 }
```

I hope its work for you

Comment: it gives me (Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()')

Comment: it still the same :(

Comment: i think that it is in (ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar) which it in lib folder, when i delete this jar it works, but it appears that i can't make exclude to a jar file. any idea how to use the tow jars without conflicts ?

Comment: you can exclude jpos  package from ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar as above just eemove  `.JposException` from behind

Comment: i can't add exclude to jar file, it still give me (Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()')

Comment: you are missing round brackets